# SQL Server 2005 Express installed after SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I already had the SQL Server 2008 Express engine installed (just the bit that comes with VS 2008 Express). I then installed SQL Server 2005 Express followed by SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express, all of which seemed to install OK without any errors. However, when I run SQL Server 2005 Management Studio and enter the Server name as machine name\SQLEXPRESS and click Connect I get the message:
 "This version of SQL Management Studio Express can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and 2005 servers".
  Presumably the instance name SQLEXPRESS refers to the 2008 version, is  the 2005 instance a different name, or is it a different problem? Any ideas please, thanks

Comment: There probably is more to your scenario, but just FYI you can use the SQL 2008 Management Studio to connect and manage SQL Serer 2005 instances.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the SQL 2008 Express took the 'SQLEXPRESS' instance name. The 2005 toolset cannot connect to 2008. You need to find out the isntance name under which the 2005 VS installed it's Express. Easiest way is to start the Service Manager (run `services.msc`)and see the instance name there.

Answer (score 0):

Run "services.msc" and check the service name that is running your SQLServer 2005 Express instance. You should use it, and not "SQLEXPRESS" if it is running your SQLServer 2008 instance.

Btw, SSMS 2008 works beautifully with 2005 instances.
Check this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en) to download SSMS Express 2008. I'm not sure code completion will work with SQLServer 2005 tho.

Comment: Thanks, what seems to have happened is that by allowing the default instance name of SQLEXPRESS for the 2005 installation also, it didn't actually install a database engine services feature, only tools, toolsclient and toolsclient/connectivity against a blank instance name. I would like to install SSMS 2008 but it seems a lot more complicated and a bit confusing?

Comment: Installing SSMS was always painless to me. I edit my answer with a link to Microsoft so you can download SSMS 2008 express.